# How to differentiate between iframe redirection and manual redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I do have a site where several iframes get loaded which's content I can't control. These iframed pages may cause redirects. I do prevent these redirects by using this iframe-busting-busting-busting code:

```
<script>
  // Code from here:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed
  var prevent_bust = 0
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    prevent_bust++;
  };
  setInterval(function(){
    if (prevent_bust > 0){
      prevent_bust -= 2;
      window.top.location = '/204-NoContentResponse.php';
    }
  }, 1);
</script>
```

This works great for the iframes, but now the user can't change the url by hand and is unable to leave the page manually. If he enters a different URL in his omnibox/url bar this redirection is prevented, too.

So this post: [Disable onbeforeunload for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084152/disable-onbeforeunload-for-links) doesn't apply here, unfortunatelly.

Is there a way to let the user leave the page by entering an url, clicking a bookmark or hitting F5, but prevent iframes from redirecting?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that this site is run in an environment where users are forced to use IE9. So the sandbox attribute is no option unfortunatelly.

Comment: You can use the HTML5 sandbox attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window

Comment: I already saw that option, but forgot to mention that this site has is run in a company environment where users are forced to use IE9 which does not support the sandbox attribute.
I'll update my question to reflect that, but thx.